# Abrir um link href em php

Tags: php, link

Boa tarde. Tenho o seguinte código a seguir e gostaria de abrir os sites que tenho e com um botão para redirecionar para o login da hospedagem e não estou conseguindo. O link da hospedagem seria esse http://www.example.com/webmail

Meu código está assim:

BEM VINDO

```
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <a target="_blank" href="<?= $site . 'webmail' ?>">
                        <h4 class="page-title">webmail</h4>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Mas ele não abre o /webmail, abre somente o site normal. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual o conteúdo da variável $site?

Comment: A variável $site, abre vários domínios separados conforme é configurado pelo cliente. Por isso não posso colocar o link direto

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Verifica se o link está neste formato: http://example.com target=_blank

```
<a href="<?php echo $site . "/webmail" ?>" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Em testes o $site está buscando este link :http://localhost/multicardapio.com.br/

Comment: Ele deveria acrescentar o /webmail mas não está acrescentando

Comment: "/webmail". Altera para aspas duplas. Já tentou? você tá definindo o endereço do site direto na viariável? Acrescenta http://

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado

Comment: Por nada, se tiver tudo ok só aceita a resposta! :) Abraços!

Answer (score -2):

Sugiro alterar a linha

```html
<a target="_blank" href="<?= $site . 'webmail' ?>">
```

Para

```html
<a target="_blank" href="<?= $site . '/webmail' ?>">
```

Comment: Sim, ja fiz, mas não deu certo.

Answer (score -2):

Aqui está funcionando dessa forma.

```
$site = 'https://www.google.com.br';
```

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?= $site . '/webmail' ?>">
            <h4 class="page-title">webmail</h4>
</a>
```